# STL Map error C2679 in C++

Tags: c++, stl, containers

im having a problem when trying to print out pairs of int & strings in an STL Map:

this is the code im using:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <map>

using namespace std;
typedef map<int,string> intID;

int main(){

    intID ID;
    ID.insert(pair<int,string>(123,"studentname1"));
    ID.insert(pair<int,string>(124,"studentname2"));
    ID.insert(pair<int,string>(122,"studentname3"));

    intID::iterator IDIter;
    for(IDIter = ID.begin();IDIter != ID.end();++IDIter){
        cout <<"ID: " << IDIter->first <<", Name: " << IDIter->second << endl;
    }
}
```

The error occurs at the `", Name: " << IDIter->second` part, the `<<` is underlined saying "no operator matches these operands"

the compile error is:

> Error 1   error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a
>   right-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable
>   conversion)

Im trying to print out the second member of the pair (studentname)
I'm new to STL mapping so i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong, what do i need to change?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to include the `<string>` header. You've only been able to use the `std::string` type by incidental inclusion from other headers. You can't rely on this. Including `<string>` will also bring in the overloads of `operator<<` that allow you to output strings.

Comment: You should also include `<ostream>`, I think, since `<iostream>` defines just `std::cout` but not its members. You often get away with it though, when an implementation helpfully includes `<ostream>` in `<iostream>`

Comment: @MSalters The `std::string` overload of `operator<<` isn't in the I/O library, it's in the string library.

Comment: True. But I wrote "_also_ include ostream" since the last overload used (`<< std::endl`) requires it.